# Howto map value object in Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider a `Customer` entity that has a `Resource` object representing the logo of the customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public Resource Logo { get; set; }
}

public class Resource
{
    public string Uri { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far but getting an error because Logo is a complex object:

```
var customer = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customers");
customer.HasKey(c => c.Id);
customer.Property(c => c.CompanyName).HasColumnName("Company");
customer.Property(c => c.Logo);
```

How can I store that Resource with EF Core 2.0 as a **value object** *inside* the customer table?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to share the same table you could simply define an *Owned Entity*:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().OwnsOne(c => c.Logo);
```

By convention it will use just one table.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you! (can accept answer in 4 min)

Comment: If I need to define the column names of the complex type properties with fluent API, do I do it just as if it was a _normal_ entity? something like `modelBuilder.Entity<Resource>().Property(r => r.Name).HasColumnName("ResourceName");`

Comment: @FercoCQ You need to define those properties inside `OwnsOne` method: `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().OwnsOne(c => c.Logo, x => { x.Property(p => p.Logo).HasColumnName("LogoColName"); });`

Answer (score 1):

Read More About it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/) there have a exemple 
Search with `CTRL + F` by "Owned entities and Table Splitting"

Comment: It is a good starting point, thanks for share, but it doesn't tell so much, for example, how to define the name of the columns in the database, if you don't want the default behavior that you get using only OwnsOne(). Perhaps you could be interested in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities